# Meteor package PersistentMongo2 tries duplicate inserts

Tags: javascript, meteor, minimongo

I am testing [`meteor-persistent-minimongo2`](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-persistent-minimongo2) for offline data support. Although the off-line data feature is working fine, I see some insert failed errors on browser console: `WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error`. These errors occur randomly, sometimes it gives error for only one record some other time for three records, etc. as I keep refreshing the page. There is no error on the server side, so this is related with the client & `minimongo`.
I use the package as follows in `mycollection.js`;

```
export const MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    console.log('Setting Mini Mongo Observer');
    const persistentColl = new PersistentMinimongo2(MyCollection, 'testapp');
}
```

Apparently, `meteor-persistent-minimongo2` tries to insert an existing document into `minimongo`. But the [source code](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-persistent-minimongo2/blob/0d723f1ca011c8e358fd9c41d9b2ec1a908f1829/persistent-minimongo.js#L159) making the `insert` operation seems correct. What do I miss here?